# Redirect to new page without seo loss

Tags: seo

I have a WordPress powered site which ranks very well on Google (`example.com`). Half a year a go I started a side project at a subdomain (`subdomain.example.com`) although it is indexed by google, it doesn't rank very well. The side project has become the main project now so I want to replace `example.com` with `subdomain.example.com`.

My question is: How can I make this switch without affecting the SEO ranking?

My idea was too keep the old site up but only redirect via JavaScript to `subdomain.example.com` so the old pages will remain indexed and help me with the ranking.

Comment: I would recommend something different from what you are suggesting. I would replace the parent domain with the sub-domain. This can often be done very easily by changing how each site points to the site directory. If your sub-domain is also WP, you will have settings to change I am sure. I would do specific page redirects on the parent domain to retain existing link and search value. From there, I would redirect the sub-domain to the parent domain.

Comment: @closetnoc unfortunately is not WP is totally diffrent

Comment: 301 redirects are best for SEO. Just use them

Comment: That's okay. Should make things a lot easier!

Answer (score 1):

First  of all  - you need to  use 301 redirect.

http://www.webconfs.com/154/301-redirects-how-to-redirect-your-website/

The best effect will be if yoy  redirect each url (one by one)  to new  location . You  can do it  using .htaceess, or  there should be same plugin for it  in WP ( plugin must  be able to write redirect location in each page/entry/article )

Comment: But the new site is totally different not even WP. I could use 301 for each existing page to point to root of the new page for example ?

Comment: this  way  or another if you don't  want to loose seo  , you need to redirect old site to new (this plugin for redirection you only need to n old site) .

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to you the plugin for Wordpress called **Redirection**.
You can do this task in a easy way just pointing the old URL and the new one to replace.

Plugin Redirection > Quick Redirects (301 Redirects) - https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: The OP is not using WP for the new site. Cheers!!